# Path to self learning Calculus

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

I am currently self-learning Calculus from an old and cheap edition of Calculus (by James Stewart) which contains both single and multivariable calculus.I am aware that Stewart's book is regarded as pretty simple, but for my measly purposes,i have to admit it does the trick,neither being bogged down in rigour nor completely mechanical in nature.

I am about halfway through the textbook and am thinking of what the next steps should be once i finish it.Since the book also contains multivariable calculus,there is going to be some overlap between the Stewart book and other multivariable calc books.

I am thinking of getting the following books and would appreciate your help with some questions :

**1.Vector Calculus (Susan Colley)**

- Is it worth getting this after Stewart or do they cover the same ground?
- The newest edition (4th) is very expensive and solutions seem hard to come by.By comparison the 3rd edition is fairly cheap and i can find solutions to the problems on the corresponding MIT courseware website.Would i be missing out if i opted for the older edition,if a purchase is recommended?

**2.Elementary Differential Equations with Boundary Value Problems (Edwards & Penney)**

- Would you recommend getting this book after Stewart for Differential Equations?
- Again, is there a big overlap between Stewart and this book when it comes to the topic at hand?
- Are solutions in the back of the book/easy to find online?

I have heard that Shaum's outline of vector analysis is pretty popular too. Would you recommend Shaum or Colley?

As you can tell from the books above,I am looking for text books that are intermediate level,focusing more on concepts and exercises than pure rigour.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the two books you've listed, so this isn't a proper answer. Personally, I'm astounded anybody is able to learn calculus properly from Stewart. For people who don't want theoretically oriented books, I find the series by Marsden and Weinstein to be a good compromise, as well as Lang's *A First Course in Calculus* and *Calculus of Several Variables*, which are a bit harder. The first ones include multivariable calculus and can be found for free on Caltech's website: http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/volume/Calculus/

Comment: Thank you for responding. It does strike me as odd that Stewart seems to be at once looked down upon as a calculus text book and at the same time be recommended in many reading lists. In any case I bought stewart because i found a deal i couldn't resist ( i paid only 3.80£ for that book ) :-). Since i am already halfway through it,I don't think i am going to switch to another calculus tome that contains both single and multivariable calculus. I am just thinking about the books i should read afterwards that are at a suitable level for me.Thanks for your link though.

Comment: No one to help ? Aww

Comment: I wouldn't spend a lot of money just to get the latest edition of a book. Often the higher cost will have to do with the fact that it's a required text in some classes. I've had a look at the table of contents of Colley's book. It looks like it mostly covers the same material as Stewart's. I can't comment on the relative quality. The book by Edwards and Penney is unlikely to duplicate what's in Stewart, which hasn't got too much on differential equations.

Comment: Much appreciated David !

Comment: If you want to find math books that are at a higher level than Stewart but are focused on applications rather than proofs and theoretical problems, you may find some by looking for titles that include "for physicists." I don't know any specifically. The one area where Colley's book doesn't seem to overlap much with Stewart's is on differential forms. So you might be interested in finding a book discussing differential forms and tensors for physicists. It seems many such books have "mathematical methods" in their titles. And then "for the physical sciences"/"for physicists", etc.